# When searched result count is 0 are sorting tabs needed?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, design, search

I don't know what is the use of showing `relevance | newest | votes | active` tabs here:

[image: Screenshot]

If not needed I would be suggested to hide these tabs instead of showing them for 0 records.

### Edit:

What is the use to show this? Is it for any promotion or doing **April Fool** to users?

Comment: what does it matter either way? SO has changed navigation thrice already

Comment: `displayWithTabs` is shorter and easier than `if (hasResults) displayWithTabs else displayWithoutTabs`.

Comment: Once again, I'm going to ask you to stop submitting bug reports on Meta. These aren't bugs. These are insignificant non-issues.

Comment: @Cerbrus OP has been asked many times by multiple people now, and IIRC has been warned by a moderator. But OP just continues.

Comment: @Stijn: I am very aware of this user's history on Meta. I remain optimistic. Maybe some day, he'll listen.

Comment: Why should it? It really often seems your posts on meta come from a question that popped into your mind instead of a well thought through idea.... Again, please refrain from doing that :/

Answer (score 19):

No they're not *needed*.

But does *additional logic / styling* have to be written if there are no search results?
Absolutely not. There's no point. Don't fix what isn't broken.

I mean, even Google doesn't "hide" any tools when you get 0 search results:

> [image]